# Galaxy S3 questions

Tags: galaxy, info

I'm not very experienced with the codes on a cell phone. But I wanted to know how would someone be able to open up the `com.sec.android` application on a Samsung Galaxy S3 Cell Phone to see hidden contacts, text messages and other information ?
Thanks.

Comment: Is this related to security? Then you should flag it so. And please remove the "info" tag that has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

Generally Samsung phones comes with pre-installed applications by default. These applications are system applications which cannot be removed unless the device is rooted. Some applications use content providers to use sensitive information. Some malicious apps can use the content providers to get these sensitive information and can misuse them.

Check out [this link](https://labs.mwrinfosecurity.com/advisories/multiple-samsung-android-application-vulnerabilities/) so that you can get to know about it and the vulnerabilities.